# Firebase query to compare dates which is a string to the actual date

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I mistakenly set a date field as a string when creating the database which i didn't realize and now the documents in the db has really increased so it stores the date number as a string in the firestore database and i want to make a query where i compare if the date is between the start and end date i provided. can anyone help me out?

this is how i stored it in the docmument

```
date: Date.now().toString()
```

and the variables for the start date and end date

```
  startDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), 1);
  endDate = new Date(
  new Date().getFullYear(),
  new Date().getMonth() + 1,
   0 ).setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
```

and this is the query

```
return this.firestore
  .collection('orders', (orders) =>
    orders
      .where('date', '>=', this.startDate)
      .where('date', '<=', this.endDate)
      .orderBy('date', 'desc')
  )
```

this doesn't work, is there a way i can get around this? or i have to restructure the db again?

Answer (score 1):

Storing a date you want to query on like this is a bad idea and a common anti-pattern:

```
date: Date.now().toString()
```

The format that you get from calling `toString()` (`"Wed Oct 05 2011 07:48:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)"`) is meant for displaying to humans and not suitable for ordering and filtering by code.

You should either store your values as Firestore `Timestamp`, or as a string format that can be ordered and filtered.

---

**Storing dates as a `Timestamp`** can be accomplished with:

```
date: Date.now()
```

With this Firestore will store the value as a `Timestamp`, which you can then order and filter on with ease by passing either `Timestamp` or `Date` objects to the `where` clauses of your query.

---

**Storing dates as a lexicographically ordered string** can be accomplished with:

```
date: Date.now().toISOString()
```

With this you will be storing strings in a format like `"2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z"`, which *can* be sorted and be used to perform range queries.

---

**Update**: As you pointed out, your `Date.now().toString()` gives you a numeric timestamp in string format, e.g. `"1657889475842"`.

In that case the problem is that you're passing `Date` objects in the query, and comparing a date to a string will never give a match. You should either pass numbers-as-strings to the `where` too, or take the approach I recommended above.

Comment: when i call the Date.now().toString i get the date milliseconds but in a string form. Something like this date: "1657889475842"

Comment: Oh right, I should realize that. The problem in that case is that you're passing `Date` objects in the query, and comparing a date to a string will never give a match. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: yeah that's the problem now so i guess i have to wait a while so i can update the timestamp for the new documents which will be coming into the database

Comment: but if i'm comparing "1657889475842" to a number won't it work? like comparing  a string "1" to see if it's less than the  number 2 in javascript?

Comment: Not reliably. If you want to compare numbers, compare numbers - don't rely on idiosyncrasies of the language/platform. Here it seems you want to compare dates/timestamps, so I recommend actually comparing those types rather than mapping them to a number that you then store as a string.

Comment: i fixed it, i just converted the current date to string and it worked.  orders.where('date', '>=', this.startDate.getTime().toString()) this worked

Comment: Yup, that is what I explained in the update to my answer: "...the problem is that you're passing Date objects in the query, and comparing a date to a string will never give a match. You should either pass numbers-as-strings to the where too..."

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. This is the solution

```
return this.firestore
  .collection('orders', (orders) =>
    orders
      .where('date', '>=', this.startDate.getTime().toString())
      .where('date', '<=', this.endDate.toString())
  )
  .valueChanges({ idField: 'Id' });
```